# Regex to split a hashtag into words

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to come up with a regex which will correctly split a hashtag into its words. For example:

XP => XP
ACar => A Car
GoodCar => Good Car
OnceUponATime => Once Upon A Time
LoveXP => Love XP
AppleVsXP => Apple Vs XP
JamesBond007 => James Bond 007

Edit:
I have tried

```
expanded = ' '.join(re.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*", self.text))
```

What is a a more robust way which will address all the use cases above?

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. Try showing example data and whatever code you've tried so far.

Comment: do you need a `regex`? why not just do regular splitting based on upper/lower case?

Comment: How do you expect it to know the difference to split `ACar` to `A Car` but not `LoveXP` to `Love X P`? What if you have a tag like `MyXSize` or `MacOSX`?

Comment: @zwer You can do that based on whether there's a lowercase character after a capital letter. There's an `a` after `C`, but nothing after `XP`. There's an `i` after `S`, but nothing after `OSX`. You can't split `OSX` into `OS` and `X` though.

Comment: Yep. I am fine with keeping OSX as one word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply do this by this expression, it's totally sufficient:

```
expanded = " ".join([a for a in re.split('([A-Z][a-z]+)', i) if a])
```

it gives the following results:

```
XP
A Car
Good Car
Once Upon A Time
Love XP
Apple Vs XP
James Bond 007
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Like the simplicity of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can define several patterns to match what's considered a separate word - an uppercase character followed by a series of lowercase characters, a series of digits, a series of uppercase characters not followed by lowercase characters, etc. -  and then just cycle it over your string:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z]+|\d+|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])")

def split_hashtag(tag):
    return pattern.findall(tag)
```

If you test it with your tags:

```
test_tags = ["XP", "ACar", "GoodCar", "OnceUponATime", "LoveXP", "AppleVsXP", "JamesBond007"]
for tag in test_tags:
    print("{} => {}".format(tag, " ".join(split_hashtag(tag))))
```

You get:

```
XP => XP
ACar => A Car
GoodCar => Good Car
OnceUponATime => Once Upon A Time
LoveXP => Love XP
AppleVsXP => Apple Vs XP
JamesBond007 => James Bond 007
```